# how can I create an event handler in a loop that does not recreate itself?

Tags: javascript, this, document, addeventlistener

I have a class member lets call it remove. so to call it I write this.remove(arg)
I am building a table of  buttons that I need this function to be an event of.

so the current code is

```
var me = this
for (x iterations) {
    button.addEventListener('click',function() {
        me.remove(this) // <- document is passed via this. I need both contexts
}
```

obviously this is bad code on every reiteration the function is being recreated.

```
remove.call()
```

wouldn't work because i don't have access to the new this context until it's created.

is they're a better way to write this as to not recreate the function every time?

Comment: Is the goal not to create multiple copies of the function, one per loop iteration?

Comment: Is `this` really want you want there? It will refer to the button.

Comment: I think you've taken the M in [mcve] a bit too far (which makes a change), can you expand a bit, ideally with a **runnable** Stack Snippet (the `<>` toolbar button) showing what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It's not *very* clear what you're asking, but you can avoid recreating the function in the loop:

```
var me = this;
function removeButton() {
    me.remove(this);
}
for (/*x iterations*/) {
    button.addEventListener('click', removeButton);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I had it in my head that defining a function like this was like a capture.